# Artifactory oauth: Can I customize which OpenID claim becomes Artifactory username?

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, artifactory

In our Azure AD, admin users have two users "john.smith@example.com" and "adm-john.smith@example.com". Since they are actually the same user, both users have the same email address "john.smith@example.com".

When logging in using OAuth SSO, Artifactory will use the email address to create the username, or to match to an existing user, which makes it difficult or impossible to have two artifactory users matching these two Azure AD users.

Is it possible to configure Artifactory to pick up another claim to use when creating a user, for example the standard "preferred_username" or a custom claim that we configure in Azure AD?

Comment: Can you explain why the two AAD users have the same email address? How did you configure them?

Comment: Sure, so the first user has User Principal Name = "first.last@example.com", replicated from an on-premise Active Directory, with the obvious email address. The second user has been added manually in Azure AD, with the User Principal Name "admin-first.last@example.onmicrosoft.com". In order to get emails for that user, the user email has then been set to the same original email address "first.last@example.com".

Comment: How did you set the second user to the same original email address? That's actually what I want to know.

Comment: Find the user in the Azure portal, and hit "Edit". The "identity" section on the top has name and user principal name (which typically looks like an email address), while the "Contact Info" section towards the bottom has a separate email address field. Use the identity to set up login, use the second to configure where to send email.

A single user with multiple identities should be able to use the same email address for all identities.